# Do attack speed debuffs affect champions with auto-attack resets and auto-attack cancel spells?

Tags: league-of-legends

This question is highly focused on auto-attack based attack damage caster champions with a spell that can reset their auto-attack or cancel their attack animation in such a way as to allow them to deal their damage faster. I am interested in learning if attack speed debuff abilities/items help in anyway to limit this burst in terms of execution not damage.

So I will explain my question further with an example.

You are in a Riven vs Nasus lane you're Nasus. Nasus W(wither) is an attack speed/movement slow. Riven can Q(broken wings), AA(auto-attack), using that she can deal a large amount of damage in a short period of time by breaking her attack animation with her Q.
Now if you were to use your wither you would be able to easily escape however if you can not(she flash W(ki burst) on you) does your W affect her or will her attack timer reset on Q still allow her to AA thrice while she combos with her Q.

To conclude I simply want to know if attack speed debuffs helps in reducing a champions burst potential by limiting the amount of time it takes for them to deal their damage while you attempt to escape or beat them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me try to answer your question by taking another example: as a Wukong in lane, using my E will allow me to dash on the enemy champion and give me a buff in attack speed(AS). My burst is enormous since I would follow up with an auto attack(AA) and then reset my AA timer with my Q for even more damage. Then I would take profit of my AS buff and throw 2 more AAs before decoying away.

Now if my enemy is a Malphite. As soon as I will jump on him with E, Malphite with then use his own E, which will reduce my AS.

My burst will be reduced substantially. Why?

1° After I use my E, I will take more time than usual to do my first AA and my Q. This will allow the enemy to either leave or attack and trade.

2° I will never be able to launch those 2 AA's before decoying out because it will take too much time for me and I will be taking too much minions aggro.

3° Sometimes I will unintentionally cancel my AA just because I'm not used to having my AS reduced to that speed, which is still in advantage of the enemy malphite. (or any champions that reduces my AS)

The burst has been reduced indirectly because of the AS reduction, even though the potential damage has stayed unchanged.

Comment: ok however this applies to auto-attack cancel yes? While I completely understand your answer and it all does make sense does the same apply for the example above i ask this because riven has three auto-attack timer resets. I do appreciate the time you took to answer and your answer has made enlighten me but just a bit greedy here to know more though.

Comment: I understand I haven't fully answered your question. ;-) Although I'm not 100% sure for the Riven case, I would use the logic by saying that if her AS is reduced, she would obviously take more time to AA and thus the trade will become longer, giving you the chance to do something. Even though she can reset her AA, the time for attacking will still be longer. 
Once again, the burst will be reduced indirectly because:
As a Nasus you might have the time to use your Q and gain some life steal. You could also simply run to the tower, which will make it more difficult for the riven to follow.

Comment: ah that is where my issue was. I was not sure if after her attack timer was reset would her attack be carried out instantly or still be affected by the slow. I understand it now. Its quite interesting to be honest have never thought of it till today.

Comment: I agree with you, it's really interesting how you can actually add some "math/theory" in a game in order to become better at it!

Answer (score 9):

The answer is yes, att speed debuffs can reduce potential burst damage.

Multiple people discussed att speed debuff over the forums of League of Legends: 
[League of Legends NA Forums](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2629861)

As mentioned there:

> Well the reason for this is attack speed slows slow your animation

Even if you play a champion which has an AA reset timer. 
The actual animation of your AA gets slowed down as well.

So in your example of an Riven / Nasus setup, the wither from Nasus will slow down riven's attack animation, thus reducing her burst.